# How to find in CMAKE file if OpenCV is compiled with CUDA

Tags: opencv, cmake

i am using opencv with another library. So i would like to compile a class if OpenCV has CUDA.
i need to acheive this in Cmake file. But i cannot find any variable that tells whether OpenCV
has CUDA or not.

FindOpenCV.cmake defines these variables

OpenCV_FOUND
  OpenCV_LIBS
  OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIR
  OpenCV_VERSION

now how can i find out if OpenCV is compiled with CUDA or not from this cmake file?

Comment: From [OpenCVConfig.cmake.in](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/cmake/templates/OpenCVConfig.cmake.in#L223), it looks like you could maybe try using `if(CUDA_FOUND)`.  However, if this variable isn't documented by OpenCV, you'd probably be running the risk of this variable being renamed or deleted in future versions of OpenCV.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is the list of CMake variables, that can help you:

`OpenCV_COMPUTE_CAPABILITIES` - compute capability from which OpenCV has been compiled, can be added to nvcc flags.

```
list(APPEND CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS ${OpenCV_COMPUTE_CAPABILITIES})
```

`OpenCV_CUDA_VERSION` - CUDA toolkit version which was used to build OpenCV, if OpenCV was built without CUDA support, the variable is empty. You can check this variable:

```
if(OpenCV_CUDA_VERSION)
    # Have CUDA support
endif()
```

`OpenCV_USE_CUBLAS` - true if OpenCV was built with CUBLAS support

`OpenCV_USE_CUFFT` - true if OpenCV was built with CUFFT support

`OpenCV_USE_NVCUVID` - true if OpenCV was built with NVCUVID support

Comment: thanks for your help. it is really helpful for a newbie like me